# Fastest Way to Perform Multiple image::imageops on a Single Image Rust

Tags: rust

I'm using the [image::imageops::colorops](https://docs.rs/image/0.18.0/image/imageops/colorops/index.html) package to processs some images.
I'd like to perform a sequence of `colorops` on a single image, what's the most efficient way to do this?
Wouldn't I have to convert the ImageBuffer that the colors return into a `GenericImageView` if I wanted to use that processes image in the next `colorop`? That seems inefficient, wouldn't it be better to just pass the `ImageBuffer` that the `colorop` returns into the next `colorop`?

```
image = "0.23.12"
```

```rust
use image::GenericImageView;
use image::imageops::*; 

let img = image::open("imgs/clouds.jpeg").unwrap();

let imgv1 = colorops::contrast(&img, 100.0); //add contrast
//returns ImageBuffer<P, Vec<S>> all color ops take a Generic Image View

let imgv2 = colorops::huerotate(&imgv1, 100); //then hue rotate

let imgv3 = colorops::brighten(&imgv2, 100); //then brighten
```

Comment: It looks like[`ImageBuffer` implements `GenericImageView`](https://docs.rs/image/0.23.12/image/trait.GenericImageView.html#impl-GenericImageView-4), so you should be able to do this. EDIT: [Your code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=715e4f3f1b19c1fd20a55d43341e1ea8) compiles.

Comment: @EvilTak The question doesn't seem to be about whether it compiles or not. The question seems to be whether there's a "less inefficient" way to perform those operations, i.e. with less cloning and creating new images, and instead mutating `img`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to perform a sequence of colorops on a single image, what's the most efficient way to do this?

I assume you're referring to the fact that the `colorops` functions clones and creates a new image. Which could be seen as potentially inefficient, as in your case those operations could ideally be done "in place", thus avoiding the needless heap allocations. Though, the [`colorops` module](https://docs.rs/image/0.23.12/image/imageops/colorops/index.html) does not contain any "in place" functions, only the [`imageops` module](https://docs.rs/image/0.23.12/image/?search=in_place) does.

In that case, you could define your own `contrast_in_place` function, that takes a `&mut GenericImage`. In the documentation for the [`contrast()`](https://docs.rs/image/0.23.12/image/imageops/colorops/fn.contrast.html) function, you can click [`[src]`](https://docs.rs/image/0.23.12/src/image/imageops/colorops.rs.html#53-83) to view the source code for that function. *(Same applies to [`huerotate()`](https://docs.rs/image/0.23.12/image/imageops/colorops/fn.huerotate.html) and [`brighten()`](https://docs.rs/image/0.23.12/image/imageops/colorops/fn.brighten.html))*

You can use the existing `*_in_place` functions as inspiration for how to do that, e.g. [`flip_horizontal_in_place()`](https://docs.rs/image/0.23.12/src/image/imageops/affine.rs.html#225-237).

---

As an example, let's implement `contrast_in_place()`:

*(I've commented out the old parts)*:

```rust
// pub fn contrast_in_place<I, P, S>(image: &I, contrast: f32) -> ImageBuffer<P, Vec<S>>
pub fn contrast_in_place<I>(image: &mut I, contrast: f32)
where
    I: GenericImage,
    // I: GenericImageView<Pixel = P>,
    // P: Pixel<Subpixel = S> + 'static,
    // S: Primitive + 'static,
{
    let (width, height) = image.dimensions();
    // let mut out = ImageBuffer::new(width, height);

    // let max = S::max_value();
    let max = <<I::Pixel as Pixel>::Subpixel as Bounded>::max_value();
    let max: f32 = NumCast::from(max).unwrap();

    let percent = ((100.0 + contrast) / 100.0).powi(2);

    for y in 0..height {
        for x in 0..width {
            let f = image.get_pixel(x, y).map(|b| {
                let c: f32 = NumCast::from(b).unwrap();

                let d = ((c / max - 0.5) * percent + 0.5) * max;
                let e = clamp(d, 0.0, max);

                NumCast::from(e).unwrap()
            });

            // out.put_pixel(x, y, f);
            image.put_pixel(x, y, f);
        }
    }

    // out
}
```

---

I've created a [PR (#1393)](https://github.com/image-rs/image/pull/1393) to add these functions to the `colorops` module. You can see the implementation of `huerotate_in_place()` and `brighten_in_place()` in the [PR changes](https://github.com/image-rs/image/pull/1393/files).

---

It's important to always measure if something is actually more or less efficient, instead of just assuming. However, there is a slight exception in this case, as it is reasonable to assume that cloning a potentially huge image would be costly.

Let's measure it anyways using [`criterion`](https://crates.io/crates/criterion). *I've excluded the `*_in_place` functions from this example, so you need to add them.*

```rust
// benches/bench.rs
use criterion::{criterion_group, criterion_main, Criterion};

use image::imageops::colorops;

fn criterion_benchmark(c: &mut Criterion) {
    const IMG_DATA: &[u8] = include_bytes!("image.jpg");

    // To get a significant result, test for `N` images
    const N: usize = 10;

    let mut group = c.benchmark_group("colorops");
    group.measurement_time(std::time::Duration::from_secs(30));

    macro_rules! bench {
        ($id:expr, $f:expr) => {
            group.bench_function($id, |b| {
                b.iter(|| {
                    std::iter::repeat(IMG_DATA)
                        .take(N)
                        .map(|data| image::load_from_memory(data).unwrap())
                        .map($f)
                        .collect::<Vec<_>>()
                });
            });
        };
    }

    bench!("contrast", |img| {
        colorops::contrast(img.as_rgb8().unwrap(), 100.0)
    });
    bench!("contrast_in_place", |mut img| {
        colorops::contrast_in_place(img.as_mut_rgb8().unwrap(), 100.0);
        img
    });

    bench!("huerotate", |img| {
        colorops::huerotate(img.as_rgb8().unwrap(), 100)
    });
    bench!("huerotate_in_place", |mut img| {
        colorops::huerotate_in_place(img.as_mut_rgb8().unwrap(), 100);
        img
    });

    bench!("brighten", |img| {
        colorops::brighten(img.as_rgb8().unwrap(), 100)
    });
    bench!("brighten_in_place", |mut img| {
        colorops::brighten_in_place(img.as_mut_rgb8().unwrap(), 100);
        img
    });
}

criterion_group!(benches, criterion_benchmark);
criterion_main!(benches);
```

```
# Cargo.toml
[dev-dependencies]
criterion = "0.3.3"

[[bench]]
name = "bench"
harness = false
```

Then benchmark by executing `cargo bench`.

Here's a stripped down and reformatted version of the results:

```
colorops/contrast           time:   [106.53 ms 106.63 ms 106.72 ms]
colorops/contrast_in_place  time:   [105.15 ms 105.36 ms 105.62 ms]

colorops/huerotate          time:   [101.12 ms 101.22 ms 101.33 ms]
colorops/huerotate_in_place time:   [92.009 ms 92.093 ms 92.180 ms]

colorops/brighten           time:   [98.255 ms 98.409 ms 98.555 ms]
colorops/brighten_in_place  time:   [95.884 ms 95.978 ms 96.072 ms]
```

We can see that the `*_in_place` variants are a few milliseconds faster, when benched against 10 images. However, whether it's worth implementing (and maintaining) the `*_in_place` variants, entirely depends on the context of the project.

If you have a small amount of images and/or if this isn't being done in real time, then it might be negligible.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that what you propose is to have something as the following:

```rust
pub fn all_in_once() {
    let img = image::open("imgs/clouds.jpg").unwrap();

    let img_trans = colorops::brighten(
        //then brighten
        &colorops::huerotate(
            //then hue rotate
            &colorops::contrast(&img, 100.0),
            100
        ),
        100,
    ); //add contrast
}
```

Well, you could benchmark it. These are the results (I called your proposed function `sequential`):

```
Run sequential          time:   [38.898 ms 39.024 ms 39.167 ms]
Found 4 outliers among 100 measurements (4.00%)
  3 (3.00%) high mild
  1 (1.00%) high severe

Run all in once         time:   [39.490 ms 39.587 ms 39.682 ms]
```

As you can see, the benchmarks suggest that there is no significant difference. I don't know if what you propose is to have it instead borrow the `ImageBuffer` instead of passing it as a reference. Maybe, that's more performant but you would need to change it in the [imageops](https://github.com/image-rs/imageproc) crate and then come back with a benchmark to prove it.

EDIT: benchmarks were performed using [criterion.rs](https://github.com/bheisler/criterion.rs).

Comment: The difference you're receiving is likely due to IO. However, maybe I'm reading between the lines, but I think OP is asking, if it's possible to apply the operations without a new image being created after every operation.

Comment: Oh, the difference is not significant (I can calculate it statistically, but it is not, trust me :) ). Regarding that, I don't think you can do it a with current imageops (I could be wrong) but you could use something lower level ([map_colors](https://docs.rs/imageproc/0.22.0/imageproc/map/fn.map_colors.html) or [map_pixels](https://docs.rs/imageproc/0.22.0/imageproc/map/fn.map_pixels.html)) and try to merge all the operations there.

Comment: 0.5ms isn't _that_ significant. But otherwise, agreed :) I was/am considering adding an answer for a `contrast_in_place` that avoids the cloning. Though I'm unsure if that's truly what OP is asking with "less efficient" or if OP is just asking what your answer is providing.

Comment: @vallentin Yes, I was meaning to ask if there is a way to apply the operations without needing to make a new image every time.

Comment: @ANimator120 In that case, see the answer I have added :)